# Как автоматически перезапустить таймер?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Имеется скрипт:

Как сделать, чтобы таймер автоматически повторялся спустя, например, 10 дней? В общем, когда истечет время, чтобы таймер по-новой запустился на 10 дней. Спасибо.

Comment: @vitalik, вы сами написали этот скрипт?

Comment: И вы хотите, чтобы мы за вас разобрались в первом попавшемся скрипте и написали код? А вы такой не разбираясь - успешный программист сайтов? Так я вам подскажу - в условии в первом просто вместо вывода html добавьте 10 дней к dateFuture:

    dateFuture.setDate(dateFuture.getDate()+10;

Answer (score 1):

Если я вам правильно понял:
Через PHP в БД записываем пользователя и когда нужно запустить скрипт.
При загрузки страницы выполняется ajax к PHP скрипту который получает данные из БД и вычисляет прошло это время или нет.
И исходя из ответа PHP скрипта, он включается/не включается.